# Reduce output current with same voltage of circuit

Tags: current-limiting

I have a lm2596 module and given a 12.5v 3A input to it
Now i derive 5v 3A max output from it
The prob is the circuit when connected as a charger to phone heats up and doesnt charge well or burns out due to heat. I want to limit the output to. 5v 2A max. How can i do this? Remember that the output from the circuit should be 5v 2A max and the current should go beyond 2A keeping the circuit safe and less heated

Comment: I also have a doubt that will the output current be under 2A if i had to reduce the input current using resistors

Comment: Which phone model is yours?

Comment: Oneplus one AActually what happ was it charged ok but thr lm2596 circuit heated up much.  After it got heated i used multimeter to check the output amp and the circuit burnt out

Comment: I just want to make the output from lm2596 module  to be 5v 2A maximum for 12v 3A supply. What can i do?

Comment: you can use current limiting circuit at output of lm2596

Comment: Can you give me a link for that please sanjeev

Comment: The One Plus phones are, like all other main-type brands sold in EU and US conforming to standards and safety requirements and should not be drawing more than 2A anyway. If they do at all, since many phones (I don't know the One Plus phones personally) require a special connection of the data pins to get more than 1A. My guess is that you have a cheap pre-made module. If it cost less than $7.50 abs. minimum I'm going to wildly guess either: 1. it was badly made and heats up because of that. 2. The design is okay-ish, but you happen to have a faulty one. Or 3. Your phone is misbehaving.

Comment: Ok guys i configured the circuit with proper wiring and it ia gud for oneplus one. But now when i connect it to so y t2 ultra the circuit heats up and i fear it may burn again.  I have one doubt like if i reduce the input current then will it reduce the output current?, im a newbie so kindly adjust please

Answer (score 1):

First of all one thing should be remembered that if your power supply rating is 5V@3A, it doesn't mean that the power supply provides 3A forcefully to the device connected ot it. What does it exactly mean that the power supply can provide 3A of maximum current. How much current is going to drive is completely depends on the system (phone in your case) what you have connected to it.If your device is rated for consuming 2A only and if it is consuming more than the rated,there is somewhere something wrong. But still you want to limit the current consumption of your device then you can use current limiting circuit.

[image]

For more details you can refer the below application note

[Simple Current Limit Circuit](http://www.physics.unlv.edu/~bill/PHYS483/current_lim.pdf)